# Django multiple column join

Tags: django, django-models

I have two Django models.

One that stores activities:

```
Activity:
    -title #Exampe: sky diving
    -category
    -etc...
```

And one that stores the interaction of a user with that activity (eg: if someone did it). A record is only inserted when there a user interaction has occurred.

```
UserActivity:
    -user (Foreign key to user model) #Exampe: sky diving
    -activity (Foreign key to Activity model)
    -is_completed (boolean)
```

Now I want to select all Activities, except the ones that the current user has already completed :

```
activities = Activity.objects.exclude(
    UserActivity__user=user,
    UserActivity__is_completed=True
)
```

Now, this is not working out as expected. Django does a join based on only Activity ID and:
`LEFT OUTER JOIN "achievements_activity_rating" ON ("achievements_base_activity"."id" = "achievements_activity_rating"."activity_id")`

If other users have a UserActivity record for the same Activity, this will make the same activity show up several times in the output as duplicates. I think I want Django to do something like this:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN "achievements_activity_rating" ON (
"achievements_base_activity"."id" = "achievements_activity_rating"."activity_id" AND "achievements_activity_rating"."user" = "username_of_current_user")`

Can I solve this problem with the Django ORM? I think my models are not a strange pattern, so I would expect a good generic solution for this.

Comment: 7 years on and Django still does not support multiple fields on a join statement. Raw SQL appears to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to select only activities of your current_user

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(user=current_user).exclude( UserActivity__is_completed=True)
```

Edit:

```
activities = UserActivity.objects.all().exclude(user=current_user,is_completed=True)
activities_set =[]
for activity in activities:
    activities_set.append(Activity.objects.filter(pk=activity))
```

Comment: The problem here is that Activity doesn't have a user field. I could run the filter on UserActivity, but then I exclude all activities that the user simple hasn't interacted with yet.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But is this really the best way? Can't I do it in one query? Or should I change my model structure somehow?

Comment: I dont see another way,maybe if you change your model, but i think it's fine don't change it unless you have a good reason to not only to make shorter queries.